# Pointer to integer and back again

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, c99

First, let me emphasize that this question is **legalistic** in nature.  I am **not** asking whether the following program will work, in practice, on real implementations, I am asking whether it is legal (:= not producing an undefined behavior) according to the strictest legalistic interpretation of the ISO-9899 standards (:1999 and :2011).

The question is whether it is permissible to convert a pointer to an `uintptr_t` integer, perform some arithmetic on that integer, return it to the same value, and convert the integer back to a pointer.

So, is the following program legal (in the sense that it does not produce an undefined behavior)?

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
  int answer = 42;  void *ptr;
  uintptr_t deepthought;
  ptr = &answer;
  deepthought = (uintptr_t)ptr;
  ptr = 0;
  deepthought ^= 0xdeadbeef;
  printf("I'm thinking about it...\n");
  deepthought ^= 0xdeadbeef;
  ptr = (void *)deepthought;
  printf("The answer is: %d\n", *((int *)ptr));
  return 0;
}
```

Again, I am aware that this code will cause no difficulty on any real system.  The question is whether it lives up to the legalese in the C standard, esp. §7.18.1.4 in ISO-9899:1999 / §7.20.1.4 in ISO-9899:2011, in which the phrase "an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer": it isn't clear whether "then converted back" allows for intermediate arithmetic computations.

To make the question a little less theoretical, here is a reason why one might wish for this kind of processing to be forbidden.  If we change the example just a little bit so that the pointer is `malloc`ated instead of pointing to a local variable, and if it happens to run on an implementation with a (conservative) garbage-collector, the memory could conceivably be reclaimed during the `printf` call because, at that moment, there is nothing pointing to that region of memory.  So if the C standard makes the above example illegal (e.g., if nothing can be written to a pointer that did not hold a legal pointer value all the time), this provides a legalistic justification for the assumptions made by garbage-collectors.

But I repeat that the question is about the hermeneutics of the C standard, not about any practical or real-world outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it must work.

From how I read the Standardese, you could write the value of `deepthought` to a file (say with `fwrite`), destroy any copies of the value in the program, then read the value from the file again (`fread`). The value so read and converted to a pointer must compare equal to the original pointer. I don't find any wording that forbids this.

A garbage collector which could move the address of an object would have to take such possibilities into account.

Comment: Garbage-collection becomes basically impossible under such semantics unless one is willing to permanently leak any object whose address might have been exposed to the outside world.